# EmberData - Issue with belongsTo relation using ActiveModelAdapter

Tags: ember-data, active-model-serializers

I have a small issue with EmberData - more precisely a problem with a relationship (orderItem --> purchaseOrder) which doesn't get loaded / fetched / mapped.

**Ember Version:**

```
"DEBUG: -------------------------------" application.js:29320
"DEBUG: Ember      : 1.7.0-beta.1+canary.b1a97b3b" application.js:29320
"DEBUG: Ember Data : 1.0.0-beta.8+canary.503c75c9" application.js:29320
"DEBUG: Handlebars : 1.3.0" application.js:29320
"DEBUG: jQuery     : 1.11.0" application.js:29320
"DEBUG: -------------------------------"
```

**ApplicationStore:**

```
Dispo.ApplicationStore = DS.Store.extend({
  adapter: '-active-model'
});
```

Here is a part of my existing application. Well... it's a rather simple App Setup with some belongsTo and hasMany relationships...

**OrderItem:**

```
Dispo.OrderItem = DS.Model.extend({
  selectedQuantity: 0,
  availableQuantity: 10,
  baanId: DS.attr(),
  purchaseOrderId: DS.attr(),
  purchaseOrder: DS.belongsTo('purchaseOrder', {async: true}),
  article: DS.belongsTo('article', {async: true})
});
```

**PurchaseOrder:**

```
Dispo.PurchaseOrder = DS.Model.extend({
  baanId: DS.attr('string'),
  tradingPartner: "Sanitas Troesch AG, Simonstrasse 5, CH-9016 St. Gallen",
  orderItems: DS.hasMany('orderItem', {async: true}),
  pallets: DS.hasMany('pallet', {async: true})
});
```

**Article:**

```
Dispo.Article = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr(),
  articleNumber: DS.attr(),
  baanId: DS.attr(),
  orderItem: DS.belongsTo('orderItem', {async: true})
});
```

I'm not sure if there is a problem with EmberData or if I just doing something wrong :/

I can't fetch the purchaseOrder from a orderItem... btw. I'm using this command to test the functionality...

```
var orderItem = Dispo.OrderItem.store.findById("orderItem", 1);
```

Wait for a few seconds...

```
orderItem.get('purchaseOrderId')
1
```

This means basicly that the connection to the api service is working but somehow the relation doesn't work...

```
orderItem.get('purchaseOrder')
null
```

I don't get why this doesn't work because the other relation on OrderItem is working without any problems...

```
orderItem.get('article')
[object Object]
```

I hope you got enough information to help me out :)

Cheers,

Michael

btw.. here is a small json response of /line_items

```
{"order_items":[{"id":21,"baan_id":"22711224403-1","purchase_order_id":3,"article_id":4}]}
```